# maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I have my app.config file set up so that the maxRecievedMessageSize is well beyond 65536, any tips I can get in order to improve this?

This is my current app.config file

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding
     name="FinalInspectionEndpoint"
     maxBufferSize="2147483647"
     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
      <security mode="None" />
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2000000" maxArrayLength="2000000" maxBytesPerRead="2000000" maxNameTableCharCount="2000000" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<services>
  <service name="AGY.FI.SQLService.FinalInspectionManager">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="AGY.FI.SQLService.FinalInspectionService" bindingConfiguration="FinalInspectionEndpoint">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"  />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/AGY.FI.SQLService/Service1/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 1):

The config file looks like it's set up correctly.

Are you still getting an error, or simply asking if there's a better way to do what you're doing?  Is it possible the size of the message is larger than the value you have currently set?

If the former, what is the error you're seeeing?

If the latter, the only thing I would recommend is to set the size of maxReceivedMessageSize to a value that is as large as the largest value you expect the service to need, so you limit your exposure to DDOS attacks.

Comment: Im still getting the error. I have the binding set up in the services app.config, the clients config and in web.config on the web part of the app ( using silverlight 4 if it matters) then exact error is   

he maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Comment: Do you know how large the message is?  If the config files are set up with identical binding values than it might be that you're message is still too large.  You might want to specify a transferMode of streamed (default is buffered), which allows a much larger maxReceivedMessageSize.

Comment: I tried setting the transferMode to streamed and it indeed worked like you said. However, I was only able to receive half of the data I was trying to get. I think I'm just asking for to much from the service and am going to have to rethink our project hehe.

Comment: Figured out how to change it. Its not in the App.Config file where the message was coming from it was within the metadata config file. When the WCF Test Client, connected to the metadata address is a config file, if you edit that then you can change the size of the return value for your metadata

Comment: Continued from last comment - However editing the binding is only temporary since I am not sure where this file is located.

Comment: @Tim B - which file?  There should be a config file for the service, and a config file for the client, and they normally reside in where the Web.config or App.config files do.

Comment: It was the config file for the WCF test client, it was located in a temp folder in the users/appdata/local/temp/test client projects/10.0/ then the temp file and its located in there.

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell us, what you are sending when this exception is thrown. From my experience, this happened when I was serializing whole objects which contained a lot of properites or even collections.

One way around is to make buffer on each side and serialize object, break up result of serialization to smaller pieces, send pieces one by one, and then have them put togather on other side and deserialize. At least this solved my problem with this exception.

Comment: That's would I would have to do in the long run for I was trying to return to much data from the service.